# Programming an ATtiny85

Tags: attiny, avr

Recently I ordered some ATtiny85's from [Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2151312_-1), and I've been trying to upload code to them through an Arduino Uno, following the instructions from [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LjfkjwMqXI). I've been getting a lot of unexpected errors and I am now wondering if the chips I bought are the problem. Here are the specs from the Jameco website:

> Flash (Kbytes): 8 Kbytes
>
> Pin Count: 8
>
> Max. Operating Frequency: 20 MHz
>
> Power Supply: 2.7 - 5.5V
>
> Operational Range: Industrial (A) (-40°C to 85°C)
>
> CPU: 8-bit AVR
>
> Number of Touch Channels: 3
>
> Hardware QTouch Acquisition: No
>
> Max I/O Pins: 6
>
> Ext Interrupts: 6
>
> USB Speed: No
>
> USB Interface: No

Does the "USB Speed: No; USB Interface: No" mean these aren't programmable by my set up? Or is there is anything else I should know about these chips? Do I need to get new ones that are different?

Comment: Please post the error messages. There are a lot of warnings when programming ATtiny with these old tools.

Answer (score 2):

Before you panic (try not to panic) and buy new chips, test the existing ones. See my [page about detecting chip signatures](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) which has links to [code on Github](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches) for a sketch you can run on your Uno, to test the ATtiny85.

[image: Chip detector wiring]

---

You can also upload code from a .hex file (which the IDE produces) by using a different sketch (same code link) from [this page about a hex uploader](http://www.gammon.com.au/uploader) and wiring like this (you also need an SD card adapter):

[image: Chip programmer]

---

The first sketch and wiring should at least confirm your chips are OK. The second one is an alternative way of programming them.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to take a look at this video which explains step by step how to program the ATtiny85. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9WOwDrpRKs

From my early days trying to program the ATtiny, i have watched this video.